# How to make shader graph RenderTexture deform effect more accurate?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphic-effects, unity-shader-graph, rendertexture

I have followed a PolyToots tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3T8cKTQrMxk) to make a 'rug deform' effect.

This is great except for that the vertices aren't deforming faithfully enough to complex meshes.

Here is what I mean.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yKPcL7A.png]

The FlowerPot mesh is on a layer called 'Deformers' which a RenderTexture camera is looking at.
Then a shadergraph says to deform the Rug mesh based on the RenderTexture output.

This is the shadergraph: [image: https://i.imgur.com/ucwqtOm.png]

As you can see, the rug is deforming based on the flowerpot's shape but not in an accurate enough way. Is there a way to make the deformation more accurate?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/hRUOxOX.png]

Comment: In the tutorial, I notice they capture a particle system with just a fuzzy white blob to the render texture, representing the height of the bulge. They don't try to capture an RGB image of the mesh, as you seem to be storing in your render texture. Have you tried rendering a fuzzy greyscale proxy instead of the full mesh?

Comment: Hi, how might the fuzzy greyscale proxy be created? I gave the flowers a white material and changed the mesh to one with 6561 vertices but it's still weird. Rather 'spiky' and exaggerated compared to the actual shape! https://i.imgur.com/Ba7WTt9.png Not sure how to make the result better.

Comment: Try rendering the object in full white on a black background, then blurring the resulting image? Or position a bunch of blurry circle sprites to approximate this?